# An alternative definition of locally finite family in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

A family $\mathcal{F}$ from subsets  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
 is said to be locally finite if for each point  $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there is a
neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap F\not=\phi$ only for finitely many members $F\in\mathcal{F}$.

How can I prove the following proposition?

A family $\mathcal{F}$ from subsets  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally finite if and only if each compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$  intersects only with
finitely many members of the family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\cal F$ is locally finite and $K$ is a compact subset. For each $x\in K$ there is an open neighborhood $U_x$ intersecting only finitely many members of $\cal F$. There is a finite subset $\mathcal U\subseteq\{U_x\mid x\in K\}$ covering $K$, and the union intersects only a finite number of the sets in the family $\cal F$.

Conversely, assume that a family $\cal G$ of subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ is **not** locally finite. Then we have a point $p$ whose every neighborhood intersects infinitely many members of $\cal G$. In particular, the compact neighborhood (such a neighborhood exists since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact.) of $p$ does so. This gives the reverse implication.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like know that why  any discrete subgroup G of $E(n)$ ( i.e subspace topology (from E(n)) on G is discrete) has locally finite orbits in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and vice versa. Notice that isometry group of euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^n$ is displayed by  $E(n)$.

Comment: @bigli: I suggest that you ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Ok, @Stefan H. I wrote it in the following webpage:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584683/orbits-of-discrete-groups