# Orbits of discrete groups

Tags: general-topology, symmetric-groups

Notice that isometry group of euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^n$   is displayed by $E(n)$.

I would like know that why any discrete subgroup $G$ of $E(n)$ ( i.e subspace topology (from $E(n)$) on $G$ is discrete) has locally finite orbits in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and vice versa.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580808/discrete-subgroups-of-isometry-group-mathbbrn/580968#580968. Some people have this as definition for saying that $G$ is discrete.

Comment: Why are equivalent both of definitions?

Answer (score 1):

A subgroup $G$ of $E(n)$ is called discrete if for each point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the family $\{g.x\mid g\in G\}$ is locally finite. Since this family contains each point with multiplicity equal to the order of the stabiliser $G_x$ of $x$, the family is locally finite if and only if the orbit $Gx$ is discrete and the stabilizer $G_x$ is finite. This shows that the subgroup $G$ is discrete with respect to the subset topology. Hence the two usual definitions are equivalent. Furthermore $G$ is a discrete subgroup of $E(n)$ if and only if $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^n$.